# Invoke method using spring SPEL with property

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-el

Is it possible to use a property value to invoke a method while assigning a value?

For instance, I know I can do this:

```
@Value("${name}")
private String name; // will have the value of the `name` property
```

I wonder if it's possible to do something like this:

```
@Value("#{myMethod(${name})}")
private String myModifiedVariable; // will have the result of invoking myMethod
```

Comment: @Deadpool no reason in particular. Just wanted to streamline the properties I'm curious if it's possible at all

Comment: You could annotate the method with `@Bean` and use it like a normal property.

Comment: @dan1st  oh, interesting, even if it's defined in the same class?

Comment: The method being in the same class could cause problems if you use it as a bean as the class is not fully loaded at that point.

Answer (score 6):

After my research and a bit of testing, I found there is a way shown in this article [Spring EL method invocation](https://mkyong.com/spring3/spring-el-method-invocation-example/), But `mybean` should be a string bean

```
@Value("#{mybean.myMethod('${name}')}")
private String myModifiedVariable;
```

And if you want to call a method in the existing class then use the spring bean name of the same class

```
 @Configuration  // or any sterotype annoations
 public class TestConfig {

       @Value("#{testConfig.myMethod('${name}')}")
       private String myModifiedVariable;

       public String getValue(String val){
             return val+"testValue";
       }

  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "string bean" ?  Yeah I was trying to call a method on this class itself... which it seems won't be possible. If I understand correctly they have to be instance methods?

Comment: let me check that one sec @OscarRyz

Comment: `mybean` should be [registered as a bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html) using e.g. `@Bean` (methods), `@Component` (classes) or similar.

Comment: yup that's correct, you can also call the method existing in the same bean, check my answer

Comment: By the way, there is `#this`.

Comment: i'm not sure how to use `#this` or `#root` in this context @dan1st

Comment: Insead of `testConfig` in the spring EL expression, maybe

Comment: welp now I'm struggling with resolving the name... it says `no bean "testConfig"` found... (well with my own name of course)

I think at this point I'm going to have just stick with the constructor

Comment: `testConfig` is my bean name, since my class `TestConfig`, so in the same way you should write your class bean name @OscarRyz

Comment: I tried `#this` and `#root` it didn't work and I guess I'm missing something @dan1st

Comment: Did you try `@Value("#{this.myMethod('${name}')}")`?

Answer (score 0):

When using interface projection (in Spring Data Repository) it is possible to call a static method like this:

```
public interface MyProjection {
  // Here we are creating a 2 element list with 'Spring Data' and value taken from "MY_COLUMN_NAME" column
  @Value("#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList('Spring Data', target.MY_COLUMN_NAME)}")
  List<String> getSampleList(); 
}
```

You can also obtain a value of an enum (constant) with above notation. Sample for Spring Security check:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(T(com.acme.UserRoles).ADMINISTRATOR.name())")
```

Similar notation should work in other places. Simply remember to use full path to class